# "putty --display" parameter explanation

Tags: ubuntu, bash, putty

with `man putty` i see:

```
--display display-name
          Specify the X display on which to open putty. (Note this  option
          has a double minus sign, even though none of the others do. This
          is because this option is supplied automatically by GTK. Sorry.)
```

But i not found a guide for "display-name" neither on the internet. Can someone explain this argument?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the name of your X server, of the format of
`hostname:displaynumber.screennumber`.

You may list your displays by several commands, including `xrandr --query`.

For more information, see:

- [linuxtopia : Display names](https://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/introduction_to_linux/linux_Display_names.html)
- [Is there a command to list all open displays on a machine?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/17255/is-there-a-command-to-list-all-open-displays-on-a-machine)
- [How do I list connected displays using the command line?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/121014/how-do-i-list-connected-displays-using-the-command-line)

Comment: Thank you harrymc